# KDE: Where does klipper store user-created actions?

Tags: action, kde-plasma

Klipper has the ability to add custom actions, but I don't understand why the developers didn't add a button to simply export or import them. Manually long and difficult to transfer them from one device to another.
Does anyone know where klipper saves them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klipper saves all custom actions in `~/.config/plasmashellrc`, along with some other plasma config.
Try searching for `Action_` in the file to find them.